# FIRST ORDER BY ... THEN GROUP BY 

Tags: sql, mysql

I have two tables, one stores the users, the other stores the users' email addresses.

- table users: (`userId`, `username`, `etc`)
- table userEmail: (`emailId`, `userId`, `email`)

I would like to do a query that allows me to fetch the latest email address along with the user record.
I'm basically looking for a query that says

```
FIRST ORDER BY userEmail.emailId DESC 
THEN GROUP BY userEmail.userId
```

This can be done with:

```
SELECT 
  users.userId
, users.username
, (
     SELECT 
       userEmail.email
     FROM userEmail
     WHERE userEmail.userId = users.userId
     ORDER BY userEmail.emailId DESC
     LIMIT 1
  ) AS email
FROM users
ORDER BY users.username;
```

But this does a subquery for every row and is very inefficient. (It is faster to do 2 separate queries and 'join' them together in my program logic).

The intuitive query to write for what I want would be:

```
SELECT 
  users.userId
, users.username
, userEmail.email
FROM users
LEFT JOIN userEmail USING(userId)
GROUP BY users.userId
ORDER BY 
  userEmail.emailId
, users.username;
```

But, this does not function as I would like. (The `GROUP BY` is performed before the sorting, so the `ORDER BY userEmail.emailId` has nothing to do).

**So my question is:**
Is it possible to write the first query without making use of the subqueries?

I've searched and read the other questions on stackoverflow, but none seems to answer the question about this query pattern.

Comment: can i ask what your motivation was to store email's separate ?

Comment: Are you using the latest emailId as an indication of which email address is the user's primary email address? That would prevent users from selecting an older email address as primary. Have you considered just adding an emailId to the users table?

Comment: when users change their email address, the new address is added, the old email address(es) is/are kept for a year before being deleted (according to specs)

Comment: I guess queries can be made more efficient and meaningful with proper table design.

Comment: @NamshubWriter, I've considered that, but it would create a circular reference I would like to prevent. Also, I have the above issue in other situations too, so I would like to learn the best solution for the general case.

Comment: @Gunner, If so, please post an answer with suggestions. Your current statement is not helpful.

Comment: What's wrong with circular references? Each user has one primary email address, and you probably have many use cases where you need to find that quickly. Finding old, unused email addresses which have to be deleted is something you would do less often as an offline-task, so the query time can be slower (though it will be easier to know which email addresses are old if the user table has a reference to the current email)

Comment: Actually I made a general remark, thats way I added this as a comment and not an answer. The answer provided below is something you could look into.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> But this does a subquery for every row and is very inefficient

Firstly, do you have a query plan / timings that demonstrate this? The way you've done it (with the subselect) is pretty much the 'intuitive' way to do it. Many DBMS (though I'm not sure about MySQL) have optimisations for this case, and will have a way to execute the query only once.

Alternatively, you should be able to create a subtable with ONLY `(user id, latest email id)` tuples and `JOIN` onto that:

```
SELECT 
  users.userId
, users.username
, userEmail.email
FROM users
INNER JOIN 
      (SELECT userId, MAX(emailId) AS latestEmailId
       FROM userEmail GROUP BY userId)
      AS latestEmails
      ON (users.userId = latestEmails.userId)
INNER JOIN userEmail ON
      (latestEmails.latestEmailId = userEmail.emailId)
ORDER BY users.username;
```

Answer (score 1):

If this is a query you do often, I recommend optimizing your tables to handle this.

I suggest adding an `emailId` column to the `users` table. When a user changes their email address, or sets an older email address as the primary email address, update the user's row in the `users` table to indicate the current `emailId`

Once you modify your code to do this update, you can go back and update your older data to set `emailId` for all users.

Alternatively, you can add an `email` column to the `users` table, so you don't have to do a join to get a user's current email address.