# Give priority to ORDER BY over a GROUP BY in MySQL without subquery

Tags: sql, mysql, group-by, sql-order-by, subquery

I have the following query which does what I want, but I suspect it is possible to do this without a subquery:

```
  SELECT * 
    FROM (SELECT * 
            FROM 'versions' 
        ORDER BY 'ID' DESC) AS X 
GROUP BY 'program'
```

What I need is to group by program, but returning the results for the objects in versions with the highest value of "ID".

In my past experience, a query like this *should* work in MySQL, but for some reason, it's not:

```
  SELECT * 
    FROM 'versions' 
GROUP BY 'program' 
ORDER BY MAX('ID') DESC
```

What I **want** to do is have MySQL do the ORDER BY first and *then* the GROUP BY, but it insists on doing the GROUP BY first followed by the ORDER BY. i.e. it is sorting the results of the grouping instead of grouping the results of the ordering.

Of course it is not possible to write

`SELECT * FROM 'versions' ORDER BY 'ID' DESC GROUP BY 'program'`

Thanks.

Comment: ORDER BY has no value if run before a GROUP BY

Comment: maybe this link can help you - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3695502/first-order-by-then-group-by

Comment: check even this link. It's exactly you want - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-maximum-column-group-row.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it and work pretty well as long as there is a composite index on (program,id). The subquery should only inspect the very first id for each program branch, and quickly retrieve the required record from the outer query.

```
select v.*
from
(
    select program, MAX(id) id
    from versions
    group by program
) m
inner join versions v on m.program=v.program and m.id=v.id
```

Comment: Though `id` is usually a `PRIMARY KEY` it is possible that it is not in this case and there can be duplicates on `id`. Multiple records per `program` can be returned then.

Comment: @Quassnoi - I understand that, but how does this differ from what you have proposed? I prefer a portable query. I also couldn't see the value in the "DISTINCT program" subquery, but I could be missing something..

Comment: @cyberwiki: looking again on it I see that it doesn't, since my query relies on `id ` being unique too. My remark would have sense if the @op would want to order on another column. With an index, `DISTINCT` and `GROUP BY` are optimized for loose scan, so these queries are basically the same. +1

Comment: "without subquery" in the question, subquery in the accepted answer =(

Answer (score 3):

By definition, ORDER BY is processed **after** grouping with GROUP BY. By definition, the conceptual way any SELECT statement is processed is:

1. Compute the cartesian product of all tables referenced in the FROM clause
2. Apply the join criteria from the FROM clause to filter the results
3. Apply the filter criteria in the WHERE clause to further filter the results
4. Group the results into subsets based on the GROUP BY clause, collapsing the results to a single row for each such subset and computing the values of any aggregate functions -- `SUM()`, `MAX()`, `AVG()`, etc. -- for each such subset. Note that if no GROUP BY clause is specified, the results are treated as if there is a single subset and any aggregate functions apply to the entire results set, collapsing it to a single row.
5. Filter the now-grouped results based on the HAVING clause.
6. Sort the results based on the ORDER BY clause.

The only columns allowed in the results set of a SELECT with a GROUP BY clause are, of course,

- The columns referenced in the GROUP BY clause
- Aggregate functions (such as `MAX()`)
- literal/constants
- expresssions derived from any of the above.

Only broken SQL implementations allow things like `select xxx,yyy,a,b,c FROM foo GROUP BY xxx,yyy` — the references to colulmsn a, b and c are meaningless/undefined, given that the individual groups have been collapsed to a single row,

Comment: I disagree on the "broken" part. There are rare occurences where "undefined" is a wanted behaviour, like "random".

Comment: It is broken behaviour with respect to ISO 9075.

Comment: This behavior was added to simplify joins with `GROUP BY` when one of the tables is joined on a `PRIMARY KEY`, like this: `SELECT a.*, SUM(b.value) FROM a JOIN b ON b.a = a.id GROUP BY a.id`. Normally, you would need to add all fields from `a` into `GROUP BY`, though all values from `a` are guaranteed to be same within the group.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT  v.*
FROM    (
        SELECT  DISTINCT program
        FROM    versions
        ) vd
JOIN    versions v
ON      v.id = 
        (
        SELECT  vi.id
        FROM    versions vi
        WHERE   vi.program = vd.program
        ORDER BY
                vi.program DESC, vi.id DESC
        LIMIT 1
        )
```

Create an index on `(program, id)` for this to work fast.

Regarding your original query:

```
SELECT * FROM 'versions' GROUP BY 'program' ORDER BY MAX('ID') DESC
```

This query would not parse in any `SQL` dialect except `MySQL`.

It abuses `MySQL`'s ability to return ungrouped and unaggregated expressions from a `GROUP BY` statement.

Comment: Isn't this heavier than my current query? It has two subqueries that both need to hit the DB, whereas the one I'm currently using has one from a DB and then the results of this temporary table are queried in-memory....

Comment: wrt your edit: Yes, which is fine by me. It's an in-house webapp, and won't be using anything but MySQL. But even then, it's not working. Oh, and it works in SQLite.

Comment: @ComputerGuru: your current query is wrong so it does not matter whether it is heaver or lighter. As long as you have an index on `program, id`, the query will be efficient: it will use a loose index scan to do `DISTINCT` and a single index seek to find a `ORDER BY / LIMIT 1` within each group. `DISTINCT` list is less in size than complete recordset.

Comment: @ComputerGuru: again: your current query is wrong. It can break any second, as soon as the optimizer decides to do `GROUP BY` in several steps.

Comment: @Quassnoi: "current query is wrong..." which query? and how is it "wrong?" The one I'm currently using is the very first one in the post, and it works great... Just wondering if there's a more efficient way. I don't care about being "right" I just care about a well-performing and simple solution.

Comment: @ComputerGuru: both in your post are. They are wrong as in "wrong": they return a *random* record within each group. It is not guaranteed that the record they return is the one holding the `MAX(id)`. By a concurrence of circumstances, the query now may return a record holding `MAX(id)` from the `GROUP BY` query, because it is the record it first finds on its way. However, when a resultset will stop fitting into memory, the `GROUP BY` will need to be done in several steps, and on this point your query will break.

Comment: @ComputerGuru: see http://explainextended.com/2010/11/03/10-things-in-mysql-that-wont-work-as-expected/ , examples `4` and `3`.