# MySQL grouping/ordering by timestamp doesn't work as expected

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I'm trying to implement something similar to Google store locator here but with GPS events of vehicles so there are multiple events per vehicle. The data for this is in the EventData table.

Here's the format of the table & some sample data - timestamp is generated to now with minor different for ease:

```
    deviceID|timestamp |longitude|latitude|
    1       |1323777977|73.52    | 18.55  |         
    2       |1323777973|73.52    | 18.55  |
    1       |1323777833|73.52    | 18.55  |
    1       |1323778111|73.52    | 18.55  |
    3       |1323777912|73.52    | 18.55  |
    2       |1323777922|73.52    | 18.55  |
    3       |1323777971|73.52    | 18.55  |
    3       |1323777831|73.52    | 18.55  |
    1       |1323777957|73.52    | 18.55  |
    1       |1323778111|73.52    | 18.55  |
```

Here's the query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(`EventData`.`deviceID`),`EventData`.`timestamp`,`EventData`.`latitude`, `EventData`.`longitude`,
 (6371 * acos( cos( radians(18.52) ) * cos( radians( `EventData`.`latitude` ) ) * cos( radians( `EventData`.`longitude` ) - radians(73.58) ) + sin( radians(18.52) ) * sin( radians( `EventData`.`latitude` ) ) ) ) 
   AS distance FROM `EventData` AS `EventData` 
    WHERE `EventData`.`timestamp` >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date_sub(now(), INTERVAL 6 day)) AND `EventData`.`timestamp` <= UNIX_TIMESTAMP(now()) AND `EventData`.`accountID` = 'sysadmin' 
     GROUP BY `EventData`.`deviceID` 
     HAVING distance < 5 
     ORDER BY `EventData`.`timestamp` DESC;
```

What I'm trying to get is the vehicle nearest (less than 5KM or 10 miles) to the lat/lon 18.52, 73.58 and as there would be multiple such entries, grouping them by EventData.deviceID (their unique ID) and finally ordering by timestamp to get the latest record per device. I'm using this section as the table already has an index & using this function as well speeds up the response considerably:

```
AND `EventData`.`accountID` = 'sysadmin'
```

Obviously I'm doing something very wrong as unique vehicles are selected but their timestamps imply that they are neither the earliest or the latest records. Am a MySQL n00b, please don't judge!

`http://code.google.com/apis/maps/articles/phpsqlsearch.html` is the Google example for a store locator but with unique store records.

Comment: "and finally ordering by timestamp" - no you should select only the latest (by timestamp) for each vehicle *before* you go to the effort of calculating their position

Comment: @symcbean I added MAX(`EventData`.`timestamp`) in the SELECT statement itself and it works without a subquery! Please post this as an answer so I can accept it..

Comment: @symcbean This query takes upto 0.67sec and a LOT of cpu!  Index is as following: accountID 0 A  
deviceID 0 A 
timestamp 0 A 
statusCode 703 A

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what solved my problem.

In the SELECT statement, I used (thanks to @symcbean):

```
MAX(`EventData`.`timestamp`)
```

This removed the need to use an Order By clause (which wasn't working anyway).
However, the query was still slow and took over 500ms to execute while using up lots of CPU. So I calculated the current timestamp and the 6 days previously timestamp in PHP and then executed the query, voila! 200 ms only and optimum CPU usage!

Acc. to the EXPLAIN data output, it uses a temporary table & filesort as well.

This link may help getting an even more optimum query with "inner join", etc but I'm not sure how to! http://kristiannielsen.livejournal.com/6745.html

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4716369/give-priority-to-order-by-over-a-group-by-in-mysql-without-subquery

Answer (score 0):

Try sort by

```
ORDER BY MAX(`EventData`.`timestamp`) DESC;
```